# Linking to a wordpress page where articles are filtered by custom field data

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

I have to link to an archive page in wordpress and show only posts with some specific "meta_value". The "archive.php" in my template only looks for "category", "day", "month" etc. but i need to have the possibility to filter by "meta_value" of a custom field. I have seen  this on another website:

"www.mywebsite.com/cities/?city=seelbach"

(adress bar of browser) and i tried it but nothing happens.

this is my loop:

```
    <?php
        $temp = $wp_query;
        $wp_query= null;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
        $wp_query->query('&showposts=6'.'&paged='.$paged); 
    ?>
    <?php $count = 0; ?>
    <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); $count++; ?>

        <li class="cf">

            <div class="jobs-stream-leftcol">
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

                <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'description', true); ?>
                <br />
                <strong>Wo:</strong> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'zip', true); ?>, <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'city', true); ?>
                <br />
                <strong>Frei ab:</strong> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date', true); ?>
            </div>


            <div class="jobs-stream-rightcol">
                <a href="#" class="jobs-stream-link-go">› Jetzt bewerben</a><br />
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">› Mehr Info</a>
            </div>

        </li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>        

    </ul>
```

Comment: Are you looking to filter the content displayed with the URL pram? some code of your loop will be helpful

Comment: i have a standard loop, edited my question. i followed this tutorial: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/tutorials/creating-wp-archive-custom-field-filter/ but nothing happens, i think this will only work with the "advanced custom fields"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with small edits

```
   <?php
        $cityvar = $_POST["city"];
        $temp = $wp_query;
        $wp_query= null;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
        $wp_query->query('&showposts=6'.'&paged='.$paged); 
    ?>
    <?php $count = 0; ?>
    <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); $count++; 

    if (get_your_custom_meta_Value_here() == $cityvar){

    ?>

        <li class="cf">

            <div class="jobs-stream-leftcol">
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

                <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'description', true); ?>
                <br />
                <strong>Wo:</strong> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'zip', true); ?>, <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'city', true); ?>
                <br />
                <strong>Frei ab:</strong> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date', true); ?>
            </div>


            <div class="jobs-stream-rightcol">
                <a href="#" class="jobs-stream-link-go">› Jetzt bewerben</a><br />
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">› Mehr Info</a>
            </div>

        </li>

    <?php
    }
    endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: okay i made a page ("clubs") and i have put the loop in that page and than i link to "www.mywebsite.com/clubs/?city=berlin" but i get a 404 error. do i have to replace "get_your_custom_meta_Value_here"?

Comment: yes http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields and 404 because that is not how u link stuff in wordpress, View the page then append ?city=berlin on the end

Answer (score 0):

You will have to dig into the code a little bit. Assuming you have a query string:

```
//Get the query string
$myMetaValue = $_GET['myMetaKey']; 

//Set Up your arguments including the metaValue
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'any',
  'meta_query' => array(
   array(
    'key' => 'myMetaKey',
    'value' => $myMetaValue
  )
)

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: you mean i have to edit the loop on the landing page to get the URL paramters?

Comment: That's what I would do. Wherever the post is being displayed is where you will want to add this